# Simplify docker build and deploy process for Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am using docker to deploy a spring boot app.
So first I use

`1. mvn package`

to create a jar file in the specified directory in Docker file.

Then I delete the previously created docker image file, build new one, tag one and then push

```
2. docker image ls

3. docker image rm -f IMAGE_ID

4. docker build --tag=APP_NAME .

5. docker tag APP_NAME DOCKER_HUB_REPO/DOCKER_HUB_PROJECT:TAG

6. docker push DOCKER_HUB_REPO/DOCKER_HUB_PROJECT:TAG
```

Then I go to the server and stop a running container, delete previously created image and then deploy the newly created image

```
7. docker ps

8. docker stop CONTAINER_ID

9. docker image ls

10. docker image rm -f IMAGE_ID

11. docker run -d -p PORT:PORT DOCKER_HUB_REPO/DOCKER_HUB_PROJECT:TAG
```

This all seems very tiresome and boilerplate. Is there a better and a simplified way to perform this operation.

Comment: Use Jenkins to automate all this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dockerfile Maven plugin](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven). Add a similar configuration to your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
  <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${dockerfile-maven-version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>build</goal>
        <goal>push</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <username>repoUserName</username>
    <password>repoPassword</password>
    <repository>spotify/foobar</repository>
    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
    <buildArgs>
      <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
    </buildArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then using `mvn deploy` will build your Docker image. Read the [documentation](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) for details.

Comment: I have tried this and I am getting this error, Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: denied: requested access to the resource is denied Do you know how to fix this, I am already logged in using docker login

Comment: I've edited my answer. Add <username> and <password> elements to the <configuration> element. Read the dedicated page about [Authentication](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/blob/master/docs/authentication.md) for details.

Comment: If needed, it's also possible to store credentials in `settings.xml`.